Expand/Collapse Row in MUI (via DataGrid)
Please help me by expanding lines in mui. I'm trying build drop-down rows in my table (separately for each row of the table) inside a table built on the basis of Material UI. Due to reading my material on the Internet, I was unable to achieve consistent results.
I've var (inside another var)
const columns = [
        {
            field: 'cheks',
            headerName: '',
            width: 50,
            renderCell: () => {
                return (
                    <Typography>
                        <IconButton size='small' onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
                            {open ? <RemoveIcon /> : <ControlPointIcon />}
                        </IconButton>
                        <Collapse in={open} timeout='auto' unmountOnExit>
                            <Box sx={{ margin: 1 }}>
                                <Typography>{open ? 1 : 2}</Typography>
                            </Box>
                        </Collapse>
                    </Typography>
                )
            },
        },

        {
            field: 'name',
            headerName: 'Сервисы',
            width: 180,
            cellClassName: 'name-column--cell',
        },
...,
...,
...

But I only get dropdown (number 1 when I click to icon) for one column (and for all rows at once). I understand it. But I won't understand how to achieve my result which I asked above.
I'll check codes like this:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/determined-monad-hw7jhd?file=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.js
but still not undestand how I can modify my code.
Full code below:
import * as React from 'react'
import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material'
import { DataGrid, GridToolbar } from '@mui/x-data-grid'
import { tokens } from '../../theme'
import { GetApiServices } from '../../data/mociktData'
import Header from '../../components/Header'
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material'
import { LineChart } from '@mui/x-charts/LineChart'
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton'
import ControlPointIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ControlPoint'
import RemoveIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Remove'
import Collapse from '@mui/material/Collapse'

const Monitoring = () => {
    const theme = useTheme()
    const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode)
    const data = GetApiServices[0].data.result
        .filter(item => 'metric' in item)
        .map(item => {
            const ret = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(item.metric))
            ret['value'] = item.value[1]
            return ret
        })

    const m = new Map()
    const r = []

    for (const item of data) {
        const current = m.get(item.name) || 0
        m.set(item.name, current + parseInt(item.value))
    }
    for (let [key, value] of m.entries()) r.push({ name: key, value: value })

    const pData = [2400, 1398, 9800, 3908, 4800, 3800, 4300]
    const xLabels = [
        'Page A',
        'Page B',
        'Page C',
        'Page D',
        'Page E',
        'Page F',
        'Page G',
    ]

    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)
    const columns = [
        {
            field: 'cheks',
            headerName: '',
            width: 50,
            renderCell: () => {
                return (
                    <Typography>
                        <IconButton size='small' onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
                            {open ? <RemoveIcon /> : <ControlPointIcon />}
                        </IconButton>
                        <Collapse in={open} timeout='auto' unmountOnExit>
                            <Box sx={{ margin: 1 }}>
                                <Typography>{open ? 1 : 2}</Typography>
                            </Box>
                        </Collapse>
                    </Typography>
                )
            },
        },

        {
            field: 'name',
            headerName: 'Services',
            width: 180,
            cellClassName: 'name-column--cell',
        },

        {
            field: 'day',
            headerName: 'Dashboards',
            flex: 1,
            margin: 1,
            headerAlign: 'center',
            align: 'center',
            width: 500,
            renderCell: () => {
                return (
                    <Box flex-direction='column'>
                        <LineChart
                            // width={1200}
                            height={200}
                            series={[{ data: pData, label: 'pv' }]}
                            xAxis={[{ scaleType: 'point', data: xLabels }]}
                        />
                    </Box>
                )
            },
        },

        {
            field: 'access',
            headerName: 'Сейчас',
            width: 180,
            headerAlign: 'center',
            align: 'center',
            cellClassName: 'name-column--cell',
            renderCell: ({ row: { value } }) => {
                return (
                    <Box
                        width='50%'
                        m='0 auto'
                        marginTop='80px'
                        p='5px'
                        display='flex'
                        justifyContent='center'
                        alignItems='center'
                        backgroundColor={
                            value === 4
                                ? colors.greenAccent[700]
                                : value === 3
                                ? colors.orange[500]
                                : value === 2
                                ? colors.orange[500]
                                : value === 1
                                ? colors.redAccent[700]
                                : value === 0
                                ? colors.redAccent[700]
                                : colors.orange[500]
                        }
                        borderRadius='4px'
                    >
                        <Typography color={colors.grey[100]} sx={{ ml: '5px' }}>
                            {value === 4
                                ? 'Available'
                                : value === 3
                                ? 'Minor'
                                : value === 2
                                ? 'Minor'
                                : value === 1
                                ? 'Warning'
                                : value === 0
                                ? 'Offline'
                                : 'wrong'}
                        </Typography>
                    </Box>
                )
            },
        },
    ]

    return (
        <Box m='20px'>
            <Header
                title='Status Of'
                subtitle='Something Info'
            />
            <Box
                m='40px 0 0 0'
                height='75vh'
                sx={{
                    '& .MuiDataGrid-root': {
                        border: 'none',
                    },
                    '& .MuiDataGrid-cell': {
                        borderBottom: 'none',
                    },
                    '& .name-column--cell': {
                        color: colors.greenAccent[300],
                    },
                    '& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders': {
                        backgroundColor: colors.blueAccent[700],
                        borderBottom: 'none',
                    },
                    '& .MuiDataGrid-virtualScroller': {
                        backgroundColor: colors.primary[400],
                    },
                    '& .MuiDataGrid-footerContainer': {
                        borderTop: 'none',
                        backgroundColor: colors.blueAccent[700],
                    },
                    '& .MuiCheckbox-root': {
                        color: `${colors.greenAccent[200]} !important`,
                    },
                    '& .MuiDataGrid-toolbarContainer .MuiButton-text': {
                        color: `${colors.grey[100]} !important`,
                    },
                }}
            >
                <DataGrid
                    getRowHeight={() => 'auto'}
                    rows={r}
                    columns={columns}
                    options={options}
                    getRowId={row => row.name}
                    components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}
                />
            </Box>
        </Box>
    )
}

export default Monitoring



well currently from what i can see you only have 1 open variable which is being used for all you rows which is why they all open when you click open. However you are using a DataGrid from MUI and the example you linked uses a Table Component from mui. I would recommend using a table and creating tablerows yourself so that you can manage the states of each row etc. But if you want to keep using the datagrid component, you should look at this example from mui. MUI Example If it still doesn't work I'll still help

by dropdown what do you mean?
A row cell contains a dropdown or the whole row will open a dropdown?

You can use a Select component to render dropdown inside cell. I have implemented an example here.
If you want to render dropdown rows refer this.
